# Why couldn't Nantie Hayward continue his international cricket career for long?

Tags: cricket

[Nantie Hayward](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nantie_Hayward) was a South African fast bowler who started his international career in 1998/99. [I watched his bowling](https://youtu.be/Ob4nAn3Ahow). He was very fast and accurate. At that time, everyone watching him playing thought that SA found a perfect replacement for Alan Donald.

However, he only played 37 international matches and retired from all forms of cricket in 2012.

Why couldn't Nantie Hayward continue his international cricket career for long?

Comment: Most of the article on him mentions, [In January 2003, he signed a deal with Worcestershire, due to which he could not take part in international matches.](https://www.sportspundit.com/cricket/cricketers/6510-nantie-hayward)

Comment: @RamChandraGiri That's not really an answer to the question; he joined Worcestershire _because_ he wasn't getting selected for international matches so there was no value in staying in the SA provincial setup and being eligible for selection.

Comment: @PhilipKendall True, but couldn't write justifiable answer "Why couldn't Nantie Hayward continue his international cricket career for long?". So, added it as comment.

Answer (score 1):

He [signed a deal with Worcestershire](https://www.espncricinfo.com/player/nantie-hayward-45419) which excluded him from being able to be picked for the national side.  He availed himself for selection again in 2004, and was picked for the team for a tour of Sri Lanka where he got 4 wickets in 2 tests. After that he just wasn't selected again.